# Does mongodb read from a secondary member of a replica set when using 'movechunk' to balance a shard cluster?

Tags: mongodb, replication, sharding, migrate, chunks

With the 'movechunk' command (and consequently when the balancer is running), do reads and locks happen on the primary or secondary member of a replica set?

Our application is not currently reading from secondaries, so it would be nice if the shard balancer / movechunk command read from and only locked the secondary member without affecting performance of the primary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shard balancer must read from and perform writes to the primary members of shards during a migration. This is necessary to maintain a consistent state of data across shards. However, the locking that happens during reads and writes during migrations is no different from what happens during normal reads and writes to the system. So, these should not have a significant performance impact.

If you do find that migrations are causing noticeable performance slowdowns, this could be a sign that your cluster has other problems. For example, if you've picked a less-than-optimal shard key, that could lead to very frequent migrations, which would be taxing on your system. Or, if your system is already operating under a very heavy load that is close to capacity, a migration might just add enough extra work to slow performance in a notable way.

Comment: That makes sense. I haven't even gotten to testing performance of the shard cluster - right now, migrations/balances are being used to transfer off of our gigantic/monolithic single mongo server onto other shards, at which point I'll drain and remove the single mongo server from the cluster. It's this initial balancing that's taking a while, but that server is already under heavy stress, so I was wondering if converting it to a replica set would help performance. The other shards are already replica sets.

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using?  One thing that you could try to lower the impact of this giant migration is to require migration-related writes to propagate through to secondaries on the new shards before the balancer can continue (see [_secondaryThrottle](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-sharded-cluster-balancer/#sharded-cluster-config-secondary-throttle))   This will slow the migration down, adding less stress to your server.  If you're using MongoDB v. 2.4 or newer, this option is enabled by default, so you might already be using it.

Comment: The locks are actually different, MongoDB will use a distributed transactional lock between the two shards to ensure isolation, consistency and durability of chunk migration.